# Error adding Controller Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web-config

Trying to add a Controller with scaffolding and getting an error.  Seems to have to do with my Connection String.

`"unable to retrieve metadata for DOTNETMEMBER.Song.  Failed to set database initializer type of type DOTNET.DataContextInitializer, DOTNETMEMBER' specified in the application configuration.  Entries should be in the form of 'key=DatabaseInitializerForType MyNamespace.MydbContextClass, MyAssembly'.`  The initializer class must have parameterless constructor.  See inner exception for details.

Here's my connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|RTDOTNETMEMBER.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <!--Used to initialize the database-->
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType DOTNET.DataContext, DOTNETMEMBER" value="DOTNET.DataContextInitializer, DOTNETMEMBER" />
  </appSettings>
```

Is it because of SQL Compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't a comprehensive answer because I don't fully understand the reasons why, but when I ran into the same issue this workaround allowed me to just get on with things and stop scratching my head:

1. Go into Web.config and comment out the line containing the `DatabaseInitializerForType` key (shortcut: place your cursor on the line then ctrl-K and ctrl-C).
2. Build the project (ctrl-shift-B)
3. Add your controller scaffolding as normal.
4. Uncomment the initializer key in Web.config (ctrl-K, ctrl-U).

Yes, it's a bit of a random-stab-in-the-dark approach, but I'll leave it here in case it helps anyone else googling the same issue!